# Maven package phase: how to depend on package artifacts from other projects

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have this Maven project structure:

```
-- top
  -- a
     produces a.jar and a-capsule-fat.jar
  -- b
     produces b.jar and b-capsule-fat.jar
  -- pkg
     produces all.tar.gz, which contains a-capsule.jar and b-capsule.jar
```

I am using the `capsule-maven-plugin` to build fat jars in a couple of projects, as shown above. Normally `capsule` is run during the `package` phase. I then want to assemble the capsule jars into a `tar.gz` for deployment purposes. I am using the `maven-assembly-plugin` in project `pkg` to make the tar.

But the `maven-assembly-plugin` also normally runs during the `package` phase, and it's running before the capsule jars are created.

Can I specify a assembly dependency or ordering that will force maven to create the capsule jars first? Alternatively I could build the assembly in a later phase, but there are no really suitable later ones (in `install`? there is no `post-package`).

---

POST-ANSWER: I am including some pieces of the working code for posterity:

dependencies in `pkg/pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>thegroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>a</artifactId>
  <version>theVersion</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <classifier>capsule-fat</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>thegroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>b</artifactId>
  <version>theVersion</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <classifier>capsule-fat</classifier>
</dependency>
```

assembly plugin settings in `pkg/pom.xml`:

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>build-tar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/pkg.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

pkg.xml (referenced above):

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>ustc-archive-pkg</id>

  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>*:jar:capsule-fat</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the definition for the capsule-maven-plugin appears before the maven-assembly-plugin. When there are executions bound to the same phase, Maven uses the order of the plugin definitions in the POM to break the tie.

---- edit ----

Make sure the dependencies on `a` and `b` include a classifier:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>theGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>theVersion</version>
    <classifier>capsule-fat</classifier>
</dependency>
```

See if that does it.

Comment: They are in different poms. The poms for `a` and `b` make the capsules, and the pom for `pkg` does the assembly.

Comment: Does the `pkg` pom list `a` and `b` as dependencies?

Comment: Yes, but that does not seem to affect the order in the `package` phase. I would like to specify a dependency on a-capsule.jar and b-capsule.jar. `scope` and `type` don't seem to help.